# Create Pundit Policies to API controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

How to create `Policies` for API-Controller's using `Pundit gem`?

Api controller path: `/app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb`

```
#posts_controller.rb

class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
  ......
  end


  def update
  ......
  end

  def delete
  ......
  end

end
```

I have `Controller` for the same and the corresponding `Model`

controller path: `/controllers/posts_controller.rb`

```
#posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
  ......
  end


  def update
  ......
  end

  def delete
  ......
  end

end
```

I have created the policies for `posts controller`. How to create the same for API's Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pundit is resource-based, not controller-based. When you call `authorize` and pass it a resource, Pundit cares about the action name and the resource type, but it does not care about the controller name.

Regardless of whether you call from the Api::PostsController:

```
# /app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb

class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    authorize @post
  end
end
```

or from your original PostsController:

```
# /app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    authorize @post
  end
end
```

So long as `@post` is a member of the `Post` class, you can call `authorize @post` from the controller of a parent or child or a completely unrelated controller, it doesn't matter. In all cases Pundit will go and look for a method called `create?` within app/policies/post_policy:

```
# app/policies/post_policy.rb

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.. Tnx